# Is there simple implementation of segment tree for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tree, segment-tree

I need segment tree for solving of my task. Should I develop my own segment tree, or there is any good implementation of such tree?

I need the following operations:

1. Segment update: `tree.add(from, to, value)`
2. Segment sum: `tree.sum(from, to)`

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at [this](https://liangsun.org/posts/a-python-implementation-of-segment-tree/)

Comment: @BhargavRao, this tree have mistakes.

Comment: What about [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47596/segment-tree-in-python3)

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/segmenttree is the first example. The second tree has fully other interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [pypi.python.org/pypi/segmenttree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/segmenttree). I recommend you to use it because I have fixed mistakes. (Actually they are just bad examples ;-)

It supports `sum` as one of it's features, which I think is what you right need.

If you find any mistakes or you have any suggestions, just drop me a message or just submit a pull request on github.